# how to scanf when you have string and double variables

Tags: c, string, double, scanf

I need to `scanf` data in this form: string whith spaces: 22.22kn 2.22L . (kn-kuna is croatian cuurency)
So I need to save it in one `string` an two `double` variables and I need to avoid colon, blank spaces,kn and L.
I tried this:

```
 scanf(" %[^:] %lfL %lfkn\n",tmpName,&tmpQuant,&tmpPrice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. It's

```
//   colon --+    +-----+---- the units were mixed up
//           v    v     v
scanf(" %[^:]: %lfkn %lfL", tmpName, &tmpQuant, &tmpPrice);
```

However, to make it safe you should include the length of the buffer in the string match:

```
char tmpName[128]; // for example

 //       v--- length here
scanf(" %128[^:]: %lfkn %lfL", tmpName, &tmpQuant, &tmpPrice);
```

so that scanf won't be tempted to write beyond the end of the buffer.

Comment: thank you, I just needed that second colon. I acidentaly mixed up units in question, but now i have difrent problem i get nema of srig right which is good but double variables are returned zero